# I18n JSTL - Special characters error

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, vraptor

Words with accents are appearing in the wrong way. An example is the word "Sugestões" that is showing on the screen "Sugestï¿½es".

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="proj" version="2.5">
    proj

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
      javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext
    </param-name>
    <param-value>messages</param-value>
</context-param>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>br.com.caelum.vraptor.encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</context-param>
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>


<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<div class="accordion-group ">
                  <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle " href="<c:url value='/suggestionsLinks/'/>">
                      <img src="<c:url value='/img/linkIcon.png'/>">
                      <span><font color="white"><fmt:message key="sidebar.suggestionsLinks"/></font></span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

messages.properties:

```
suggestionsLinks.title=Sugestões de Links
```

It is displaying: Sugestï¿½es Links

Does anyone know how to fix it ??

My messages.properties file is already in ISO-8859-1. I´m using eclipse and created the file by eclipse.

Comment: From where `suggestionsLinks.title` coming?Database?

Comment: from file src/main/resources/messages.properties

Comment: My messages.properties file is already in ISO-8859-1. I´m using eclipse and created the file by eclipse.

Comment: I solve my problem using this eclipse plugin: http://www.desenvolvimentoweb.blog.br/2012/10/problemas-com-encode-de-arquivos-properties/   

http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/index.html

Thanks for help of all!